# Ubuntu 18.04 USB headset not detected

Tags: drivers, usb, sound

after trying out to get my internal notebook mic running for days i decided to buy a headset.
I've put the headset into the USB slot, started Ubuntu and the Headset is not detected by the system.

`lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04e8:61f5 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:0703 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0000:3821  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The headset does not appear in `pavucontrol` or in `alsamixer` either.

This article did not help me:

[External headset not listed in Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit on Acer Aspire E15 | Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355552/external-headset-mic-not-listed-in-linux-mint-18-1-64-bit-on-acer-aspire-e-15)

I am really getting frustrated now.... what else can I try?

Maybe it could help to install the driver of another headset?